# Unable to build app for iOS, "unable to write module session file Session.modulevalidation No such file or directory"

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, build

yesterday I was working fine with Flutter, now i'm facing this issue and I already search everywhere for a solution but no success.

When I run:

```
flutter run
```

The build process starts and when its about to finish the error below is shown:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro Max in debug mode...
Xcode build done.                                           12.3s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    error: unable to write module session file at '/Users/hencke/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation': fopen(/Users/hencke/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation, wb): No such file or directory (2)
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max.
Exited (sigterm)
```

Looks like the process is trying to open this file `Session.modulevalidation` for writing, but this file really [does not exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icjjt.png) in that folder. And I don't know what to do.

Things that I already tried:

1. Reinstalling xcode
2. flutter clean
3. Clone my project again in another folder and try to build, but same error
4. Created a new flutter dummy project and tried to build, still same error
5. Rebooting machine several times
6. Give permissions to Staff to the `DerivedData` and `ModuleCache.noindex` folders
7. Deleted the `DerivedData` within hope that xcode build will recreate all the files needed, but, it created everything again but not that particular file.

So that's it, If any blessed human know how to 'recreate', or reset, clear some cache, I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Before running your project, check everything is checked when running:

```sh
flutter doctor
```

and also make sure at least a device is connected or open iOS simulator first. You can check if flutter is successfully connected to the device by:

```sh
flutter devices
```

when you make sure that flutter detect your device or the simulator, then run your application by:

```sh
flutter run
```

Answer (score 0):

After hours I finally found the solution as it follows:

Without any hope I opened my flutter project with Xcode, and then tried to build the Runner target from there, same error.

Then, I was browsing the Xcode preferences and something caught my attention, on `Locations` section I found something about `DerivedData` location, it was set as `Default`. So, I changed from `Default` to `Custom` location and I set to a new folder on my **home** directory:

[image: Example]

Then immediately Xcode created the entire `DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex` folder and with them, the `Session.modulevalidation` file as well.

Then I closed Xcode and tried `flutter run` again, and it was successfully build!

I'll let this answer to those who may come here for help.